# Ads script writes to a spreadsheet but doesn't trigger onChange event?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, onchange, google-ads-script

I have ads-script that writes to a spreadsheet but doesn't trigger a simple or a installable onChange event.

Only when I edit the spreasdheet myself this is triggered. Is there any way I can trigger `onChange` or other simple/custom trigger by an external ads script?

Answer (score 0):

Based on official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers) event-driven triggers run when a **user** modifies the structure of a spreadsheet itself. So in this case if the Ads Script modifies the Sheet it will not trigger.

A workaround would be to have an Apps Script run a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to check for any changes and continue with the process when changes are detected.

You may accomplish this with a script. You can save the last modified date, if you set triggers for every minute, next minute checks if the modified date is greater than the last one.